# I don't understand the process of this code. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could trace it for me

Tags: java, recursion, trace

```
public class recursiveReverse {

  public static String reverse(String str){ 
    if (str == null) {
      return null; 
    } 
    if (str.length() <= 1) {
      return str;
    } 
    return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0); 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    reverse("car");
  }
}
```

I get to the first time the if (str.length() <= 1) returns true, then I get lost.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: yeah, it just got to the recursive call and stayed there. Wasn't much help, but there's a high chance there's some better way to step through it that I'm unaware of.

Comment: The only way to understand recursion is to go through it iteration by iteration either with paper and pencil or in debugger.

Comment: Definitely have a read through the question @dnault linked to - that should help

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it one line at a time.

If the string to reverse is null, the method returns null.

If the string to reverse as a length <= 1, it is returned as is.

If the string is longer, the it will return the reversed sub string starting at position 1, concatenated with the first character of the string.

So: 
reverse("a") --> a

reverse ("ab") -> reverse("b") + "a" -> "ba"

reverse ("abc") -> reverse("bc") + a -> reverse("c") + "b" + "a"

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have pointed out, you would be well served by stepping through the code under the debugger.

Here's the code with "printf's":

Test.java =>

```
public class Test {

  public static String reverse(String str){ 
    System.out.println("-->str=" + str);
    if (str == null) {
      System.out.println("<--str=null");
      return null; 
    } 
    if (str.length() <= 1) {
      System.out.println("<--str=str");
      return str;
    } 
    String result = reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0); 
    System.out.println("<--result=" + result);
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    reverse("car");
  }
}
```

Output, java Test =>

```
-->str=car
-->str=ar
-->str=r
<--str=str;
<--result=ra
<--result=rac
```

Comment: this is manipulated output :p .. System.out.println("<--str=str"); should be System.out.println("<--str="+str);

Answer (score 0):

It is recursive call to reverse function till the length of string reaches one character.

In above case the string to reverse is CAR.
In first pass it will become { reverse (AR) + C}
In second pass it will Become { reverse(R) +A }
In third pass it get value of reverse(R) as R

Which will become R +A +C =RAC  as final answer.